# IIS7 url rewrite where domain is only constant

Tags: .net, regex, iis, iis-7

I want a URL pattern for the following where this link -

http://www.test.com/xyz/31052012/xyz_number.jpg

will be redirecting to

http://www.test.com/xyz_number.jpg?vin=xyz&date=31052012

NOTE: xyz_number and date value are dynamic which will be changing for each request.Only constant is domain name here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know anything about IIS7 rewrite specifically, but based on your sample source URL and output URL, you could use the following regex find:

```
^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(.+)$
```

and replace with:

```
{R:3}?vin={R:1}&date={R:2}
```

The find string is essentially just scanning through the original URL until it finds known boundaries. The brackets are used to capture groups, and the {R:x} values in the replace string are the capture positions.

The pattern expects each source URL element to be in the order specified.

Edit: updated based on edited question

This new regex assumes input string starts with xyz_number... rather than the full domain name. That seems to be how other IIS7 rewrite questions have been answered.

Comment: sorry but i have wrongly given the question..plz suggest me on my edited question..

Comment: not 100% sure, but the rewrite replacement may need a leading /